# CUDA driver CUmodule

Tags: c++, cuda, nvidia

I'm trying to understand what in practice does the CUmodule represent in CUDA driver API functions.

Many CUDA driver API functions have a CUmodule handle but what is it? Is it a handle to a dll that steers the driver calling procedures and that I can call like GetProcAddress with the name of a CUDA function or what?

Make it simple please (plain English preferred)

Comment: Maybe I will explain it in Chinese? [It's a handle to a cuda compiled binary file you load.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15407257/cuda-5-0-cubin-and-cublas-device-compute-capability-3-5)

Comment: Ah great, plain and simple. Let me accept it :*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[It's a handle to a cuda compiled binary file you load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15407257/cuda-5-0-cubin-and-cublas-device-compute-capability-3-5) (simple google lookup and logic :P)

Example from source:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime_api.h>

int main() {
    CUresult error;
    CUdevice cuDevice;
    CUcontext cuContext;
    CUmodule cuModule;
    CUfunction testkernel;
    // Initialize
    error = cuInit(0);
    if (error != CUDA_SUCCESS) printf("ERROR: cuInit, %i\n", error);
    error = cuDeviceGet(&cuDevice, 0);
    if (error != CUDA_SUCCESS) printf("ERROR: cuInit, %i\n", error);
    error = cuCtxCreate(&cuContext, 0, cuDevice);
    if (error != CUDA_SUCCESS) printf("ERROR: cuCtxCreate, %i\n", error);
    error = cuModuleLoad(&cuModule, "test.cubin");//see here!
    if (error != CUDA_SUCCESS) printf("ERROR: cuModuleLoad, %i\n", error);
    error = cuModuleGetFunction(&testkernel, cuModule, "a");
    if (error != CUDA_SUCCESS) printf("ERROR: cuModuleGetFunction, %i\n", error);
    return 0;
}
```